# I want to export my AlwaysOn configuration by T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, listener, alwayson

I am curently testing an AlwaysOn SQL Server 2019 environment and I want to check some things before we go live.

For example, I want to drop/recreate the listener. After this, I want to revert the settings to the one our provider used. So I searched for an "export AlwaysOn settings to T-SQL" script, but I couldn't fine one.

Does anyone have such a script?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the powershell command https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaAgListener is very close to what I want